# Use itextsharp to identify text which is invisible to the eyes but searchable using Acrobat

Tags: itext

I have encountered a strange situation while extracting contents using itextsharp from a PDF file. The document has a tiny block of text which is invisible to the human eyes but shows up unexpectedly while using itextsharp and also while searching through Acrobat Reader.

**Behavior - Using Find in Acrobat Reader**

When I search for the words "type text" Acrobat Reader will detect the presence of a block of text.

[image]

**Behavior - Copy paste to Notepad**

This text is not visible to the human eyes.  This tiny block of hidden text also appears while doing a bulk CTRL+A, followed by CTRL+Copy and then CTRL+V to Notepad. The complete phrase is *[Type text]*.

**Sample pdf**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ytic9WWLseX8DgeJGyMGCgVgXuMOdytP

I am using a custom location strategy to read the contents. The methods *TextRenderInfo.GetStrokeColor* and *TextRenderInfo.StrokeColor* give me non-NULL values all throughout the document.

**Vector graphics**

I understand that there is a possibility of vector graphics occluding a portioni of text , thereby making it invisible to the human eyes while still being completely legitimate. I can't say for sure what is happening in the sample document.

If the sample document is not a case of vector graphic occlusion, then does the API of itextsharp/itext offer any possibility to detect such "invisible" words?

Thanks,

Sau

Comment: I currently cannot check the nature of your sample pdf but what you describe can happen as a result of many different constructs. There is a text drawing mode that neither strikes nor fills, text can be drawn using the same color as the background, the used font may have only empty glyphs, something may cover the text, transparency might be at 100%, clip paths may exclude the text, ... thus, you need to check for very many different situations...

Comment: Did my answer help you in regard to your question?

Comment: Yes. it does go a long way to explain the challenges of the PDF document system. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text can be invisible as a result of many different constructs:

- There is a text drawing mode that neither strikes nor fills,
- text can be drawn using the same color as the background,
- the used font may have only empty glyphs,
- something may cover the text,
- transparency might be at 100%,
- clip paths may exclude the text,
- ...

For a general solution, therefore, you'd need to check for very many different situations...

---

In case of your example document we are in the "something may cover the text" situation; more exactly your idea

> I understand that there is a possibility of vector graphics occluding a portioni of text , thereby making it invisible to the human eyes while still being completely legitimate. I can't say for sure what is happening in the sample document.

is correct, a white rectangle is drawn over the area outlined here before showing the titel in that area:

[image: screen shot]

This covers your "[Type text]" which is (otherwise visibly) drawn at the very beginning of the content stream.

(Actually this rectangle is tagged as a paragraph which is not really appropriate.)

> If the sample document is not a case of vector graphic occlusion, then does the API of itextsharp/itext offer any possibility to detect such "invisible" words?

It is a case of *vector graphic occlusion*. Nonetheless it is possible to identify critical constellations like this with iText:

If you use the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`, you can extend it to also be notified about path drawing instructions (implementing `[I]ExtRenderListener`). Here you can check whether a path is filled (or stroked with a large line width). In that case you can check the text chunks the strategy has already collected for overlaps. If there are, you can warn about a suspicious construct.

You cannot be 100% sure yet that this makes the text invisible, though, because depending on the current blend mode, transparency values, original text and path fill colors, masks, and some even more obscure details the original text might or might not shine through (it might even be made *more* visible than before).